# Communication data between two differently hosted Angular Apps

Tags: angular, iframe, communication, popupwindow

I've two different Angular application. One in ng4 and other in ng5. I'm opening the second app in an iframe from the first app. How do I establish a communication channel between them?

Comment: what kind of communication do you seek? Iframe parent child communication or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll have to make an API call between the two.  You can't pass values between a web page and an IFrame like you can between angular components.